# Remove password protection from all posts

Tags: php, sql, password

So I messed up my blog ([QBobble](http://www.q-bobble.com/blog)). I had an SQL backup, fortunately, so I reinstalled Wordpress, and imported my SQL database.

Unfortunately, it password protected all of my posts. I know that I can manually unpassword protect them by going to Posts < Edit and edit the visibility to "public", but I don't want to do that to all of my posts, I want to do it to all of them at once. How can I do that? Someone said that you can do it in Bulk Actions > Edit, BUT changing the status to "public" in bulk actions doesn't work. Any ideas?

It also got rid of the excerpts for each post. They now just read NULL. Is there a way that I can get it to add those back automatically?

I'm running 3.3.1, by the way.

Thanks all!

Comment: This site is for programming help, not "how to fix my blog". Sorry, try WP's own forums.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by running this SQL query:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_password` = '' WHERE `post_type` = 'post';
```

Change `wp_posts` to match your own posts table name.